# The column name is not valid. Extent1,Column name = ... c# EF MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

like the title says, i am getting the error:

```
The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = Extent1,Column name = marketplace ]
```

"marketplace" appears nowhere else in the code and IS a the name of a column in the table.

the SQl statement that gives the error is:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
[Extent1].[marketplace] AS [marketplace], 
[Extent1].[c1] AS [c1], 
[Extent1].[name] AS [name], 
[Extent1].[description] AS [description], 
[Extent1].[c2] AS [c2], 
[Extent1].[c3] AS [c3], 
[Extent1].[c4] AS [c4],
```

and it gives the error on the column marketplace no matter the order.

one additional thing is that the marketplace column is required to be NOT NULL, but this condition is met in the database.

i used the "reverse engineer code first command" using EF to generate this and the error results on trying to turn the Entity class into a list.

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: plz share the code to understand better

Comment: syed, i added more details including the SQL statement.  the actual line that fails (fails when calling this sql statment) occurs when taking the entity class to a list

Comment: show your query (is it an ESQL query?). show your edmx.

Comment: Plz include edmx also